# Find a subspace of $\mathbb R^{3}$ of maximal dimesion so $q(\vec w)\geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

$q:\mathbb R^{3}\to \mathbb R$ is defined by $q(x,y,z)=-6xy-8xz$.

Find a subspace $W\subseteq\mathbb R^{3}$ of maximal dimesion so $\forall\vec w\in W,q(\vec w)\geq 0$

I know that $q$ has a diagonal form $diag(4,0,-8)$, but using directly the defenition of $q$ to find a suitable basis is not the right method... what should I do?

Comment: Maybe you could *guess* a subspace of dimension $2$ and show there is none of dimension $3$?

Comment: It's obvious that $W\neq\mathbb R^{3}$ since the quadretic form is nondegenerate. but how can I guess the subspace? @Adayah

Comment: the trivial answer that comes to mind is $W=Sp{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}$ but when looking at the diagonal form of $q$ it doesn't seem right... @Adayah

Comment: If you have a diagonal form, you must have a basis associated to it, say $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$, so that $q(\alpha_1 b_1 + \alpha_2 b_2 + \alpha_3 b_3) = 4 \cdot \alpha_1^2 + 0 \cdot \alpha_2^2 + (-8) \cdot \alpha_3^2$. Then $\operatorname{lin} \{ b_1, b_2 \}$ is the sought subspace.

Comment: I found the columns of the transition matrix to the diagonal form, which consist the basis: $((\frac{1}{2},0,1),(0,1,0),(-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{3}{4},1))$ but it still isn't obvious to me that the first two vectors satisfy the equation you wrote... @Adayah

Comment: I forgot to check the coordinates... the suitable basis is $(1,0,-1),(0,1,0)$ right?